# How pass body variable as a parameter to custom Exception

Tags: exception, apache-camel, custom-error-handling

I'm struggling to understand how passing a variable stored in the body as a parameter of throwException.
This is my code:

```
.when(simple("${body[errorCode]} contains '101'"))
.throwException(new IllegalArgumentException(
"Action not allowed- Error code:" + ${body[errorCode]))
 .otherwise()
```

When I run the application the message passed to ErrorHandling is

```
'Action not allowed- Error code:${body[errorCode]', no replacing for errorCode variable.
```

Any suggestions? Tnks.

Answer (score 0):

So you are using the Simple language in Java but you have some syntax issues. Nothing major. Your do not complete the delimiter of the Simple expression. Also you dont have to concatenate the string.

Change the code:

```
.throwException(new IllegalArgumentException("Action not allowed- Error code:" + ${body[errorCode]))
```

To:
    .throwException(new IllegalArgumentException("Action not allowed- Error code: ${body[errorCode]}"))

I am on the buss and using my phone so can't check if the code runs but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Does not work. The message takes the string as "${body[errorCode]}", it not able to replace the real value.

Comment: Tried with:  simple("${body[errorCode]}").getText()   and also 
 simple("${body[errorCode]}").toString()   but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start")
                        .to("mock:start")
                        **.throwException(IllegalArgumentException.class, "Darn ${body} is invalid")**
                        .to("mock:result");
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

See the unit tests of camel-core for an example

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor/ThrowExceptionMessageTest.java

Comment: Links tend to die. Please paste a snippet in the future.